# Find number of days between two varchar dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I’m a beginner at Oracle SQL and I want have two questions.

First, I want to find the number of day between two events (so when they are a yes). These two dates are currently varchars(!).

Pseudocode:
When request is yes and sales is yes, subtract sales_date from request_date.

Data looks like this:

```
Id  request request_date    sales          sales_date 
1   yes     2 feb14         yes             3 feb 14
2   yes     3 feb 14        no              3 feb 14
3   no      4 feb 14        no              5 feb 14
4   no      4 feb 14        yes             6 feb 14
```

And ideally I want this to be the result:

```
Id  request request_date    sales   sales_date   days_between_request_sales
1    yes    2 feb14         yes       3 feb 14          1
```

My second question is that if I have all these results, then how can I get the average of all the dates?

Comment: What do you mean with average of dates? In your example, ( even considering not only rows with 'yes') what should the average be?

Comment: Thanks for your question. With average I meant that I want to sum all the days_between_request_sales days (so where only request and sales were both yes) and divide these by the number of occurences. This would result in one number. If it is still unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using:

```
select trunc(to_date(sales_date,'dd-mm-yy') - to_date(request_date, 'dd-mm-yy')) as days 
from <yourtable>
where sales = 'yes'
and request = 'yes'
```

demo:

```
select trunc(to_date('3 feb 14','dd-mm-yy') - to_date('1 feb 14', 'dd-mm-yy')) as days 
from dual
```

Output:

```
    DAYS
----------
     2
```

Average:

```
select avg(trunc(to_date(sales_date,'dd-mm-yy') - to_date(request_date, 'dd-mm-yy'))) as Average
    from <yourtable>
    where sales = 'yes'
    and request = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I try this on my dataset I get the error:  'literal does not match format string'. Could it be possible that I need to change something with the date?

Comment: I used your given data and showed you a demo. However from the first record, it can cause issue. `2 feb14`. I guess there should be a space between month and year `12 feb 14`. Try that. Also try if the demo is working with you

Comment: Also your second question is not pretty clear so i didnot post any answer. Add some example for what you want average

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly now! With average I meant that I want to sum all the days_between_request_sales days (so where only request and sales were both yes) and divide these by the number of occurences. This would result in one number.

Comment: Please notice that the `TRUNC` is not necessary; also, the format mask that you are using does not suit the OP data; for example, `to_date('28 feb 14','dd-mm-yyyy')` gives `28/02/0014`, which I believe is not the date that the OP wants to represent.

Comment: User intention is not to display date rather the number of days between two date. My example suffice that need. Thanks for your suggestion. I modified as per your wish.

Comment: Downvoters please help your smart mind and post the reason. If not it would be considered as act of `foolishness` causing harm to SO,

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood how it worked  with the previous one   to_date(sales_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') is totally wrong as your format is dd mon yy so what Aleksej suggested is correct to_date(sales_date,'dd mon rr') is absolutely correct. He might have missed one condition request =' yes'.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a table like this:

```
create table yourTable(Id, request, request_date, sales, sales_date) as ( 
    select 1   ,'yes',     '2 feb 14',        'yes'  ,           '3 feb 14' from dual union all
    select 2   ,'yes',     '3 feb 14',        'no'   ,           '3 feb 14' from dual union all
    select 3   ,'no' ,     '4 feb 14',        'no'   ,           '5 feb 14' from dual union all
    select 4   ,'no' ,     '4 feb 14',        'no'   ,           '6 feb 14' from dual
)
```

Assuming that your strings represent dates always in the format you showed, you can use:

```
select Id, request, request_date, sales, sales_date,
       to_date(sales_date, 'dd mon rr') - to_date(request_date, 'dd mon rr') as days_between_request_sales
from yourTable
where sales = 'yes'
  and request = 'yes'
```

To compute the average of these resulting numbers od days, you can simply use the AVG:

```
select avg (to_date(sales_date, 'dd mon rr') - to_date(request_date, 'dd mon rr') ) as average
from yourTable
where sales = 'yes'
 and request = 'yes'
```

Comment: You commented on others post pointing what OP didnot look for but did you really look at the OP question. Your query will not give what Op want. `request is yes and sales is yes, subtract sales_date from request_date.`...your query will never produce the result which Op want,.Hence a downvote